# Foreach property in item from list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, foreach

I'm revamping a small helpdesk application (moving from ASP classic to MVC4). This is my first full MVC application. I've opted to go with Razor, and I feel like it's pretty intuitive. But I've hit a wall on this part.

I get a list of tickets from the database to display to the user. What I would like is to dynamically create a table. Right now I have put the headers in place manually, which is fine. If there's a way to do that dynamically, though, I'm open to suggestions.

But the crucial piece is to get each property from the ticket. I have a `Ticket` class that has over 20 properties. I'll be working on whittling those down to the minimum we want to display, but as a starting point, I'm trying to throw them all up on the screen.

I have the following:

```
@model IList<Helpdesk4.Models.Ticket>
```

...

```
@foreach (var ticket in Model)
{ 
     <tr>
       @foreach (var item in ticket)
       { 
          <td>item</td>
       }
     </tr>
 }
```

But I can't run that `foreach` on ticket. I'm enough of a noob that I don't totally understand why, but I think that the properties have to be loaded and so can't be enumerated by default. So without pulling up each property name, how do I just get each property's value from ticket?

I am using `NHibernate` for the queries to the db if that makes any difference.

Comment: You'll need to look into using reflection to loop through properties.  However, reflection is not usually done in a view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolutely clearest and easiest way to do this if to manually add each of the properties values to the row. This does require a small amount of "extra" work, but it is a one time thing, and 20 properties is not that much. It also gives you much finer control over exactly how each property is displayed, if it is aligned right or left, etc.

What you end up with is something like this

```
@foreach (var ticket in Model)
{ 
    <tr>            
        <td>
            @ticket.FirstProperty
        </td>
        <td class="align-right">
            @ticket.SecondProperty
        </td>
        <td class="align-center bold">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => ticket.ThirdProperty)
        </td>
        <td>
            <i>@ticket.FourthProperty</i>
        </td>
        ...
    </tr>
}
```

Stylings and such added for emphasis of customizability.

Good luck with your first MVC project!

Answer (score 0):

Foreach only works with an enumerable item, and general classes don't implement IEnumerable.  You need to put each item on there yourself.  The best way would be to use something like `Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Property)` for each property.

edit:
The best way would be to just use `Html.LabelFor` on the object itself.

```
@for(int index = 0; index < Model.Count; ++index)
{
  <tr>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m[index])
  <tr>
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but this just gives me a display of my index numbers `[0], [1], [2], [3]...`